# java logging with log4j and log4j.yaml

Tags: java, logging, log4j, yaml

Looks like java developers are avoiding logging with log4j.yaml they prefer to use log4j.xml instead

I know that there is a support for this in log4j v2 but do not understand why on internet there are no detailed documentation related to this ?

I found a lot documentation python/ruby logging and yaml. I know that java is old language but not understand why java developers are not interested in new things.

Update:

found out how to do, It was hard ;)

log4j2.yml or log4j2-test.yml

```
# why yaml http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/04/13/yaml-aint-markup-language-completely-different

status: WARN
monitorInterval: 900 # 15 min = 900 sec

properties:
    property:
        -
            name: pattern_layout_console
            value: "%d - [%t] %-5p - %c - %M(%L) | %m%n"

        -
            name: pattern_layout_console_no_threads
            value: "%d - %-5p - %c - %M(%L) | %m%n"

        -
            name: log_path
            value: "./logs"

appenders:
    console:
        -
            name: CONSOLE
            PatternLayout:
            pattern: "${pattern_layout_console_no_threads}"

    file:
        -
            name: DEBUG_FILE
            fileName: ${log_path}/debug.log
            PatternLayout:
                pattern: "${pattern_layout_console}"
             append: false

        -
            name: INFO_FILE
            fileName: ${log_path}/info.log
            PatternLayout:
                pattern: "${pattern_layout_console_no_threads}"
            append: false

######## .....    

loggers:
    logger:
        -   
            name: ch.company.module
            additivity: false
            appenderRef:
                -
                    ref: DEBUG_FILE
                    level: DEBUG
                -
                    ref: INFO_FILE
                    level: INFO
                -
                    ref: WARN_FILE
                    level: WARN
                -
                    ref: ERROR_FILE
                    level: ERROR
    root:
        level: INFO
        appenderRef:
              ref: CONSOLE
```

pom.xml

```
....
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

Comment: What is your Question?  If you are asking about the psychology of computer programmers, that is roughly 23 million miles off-topic!

Comment: I am interested in technical answers, especially why you (@StephenC) will choose to avoid yaml for logging in java ?

Comment: Because I have better things to do than switch to a replacement for a technology that works just fine in this context.  As they say, "if it ain't broken, don't fix it".

Comment: Yes! This I was afraid for, thank you for clear and honest answer :)

Comment: I have nightmares that Java is the last programming language we will ever be allowed to use at work, and that we will be stuck in these linguistic "dark ages" until well after I retire (even as the hordes in the barbarian kingdoms beyond develop less clumsy languages with which to do battle).  But yeah, I'm looking for a YAML log4j example, as well.  XML is not the most readable stuff - unless you have a specialized tool for a given schema where you don't have to actually view the XML directly, then who cares...

Comment: You should rephrase this so avoid getting dog pile down voted, though.  "Where are YAML examples?", with Java "conservatism" (anti-intellectualism) hanging in a comment.

Comment: I concur vis a vis dark age XML technology, essentially a direct derivative of 1960s SGML, more than half a century old.  It's not a wonder the average IQ has dropped 14 points over the last century and space shuttles are rusting in their cages.  YAML is superior to XML in every way, simply put, it is readable by both humans and computers, where XML is only readable by computers (unless you're a masochist with a penchant for irritable eyes).  But then XML is superior because it's familiar, and for no other reason than that.

Comment: For yaml example with Log4j, you can have a look here : [log4j.yaml](https://gist.github.com/hmarggraff/9a8024f1d5292d539895)

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be "Why are people using XML configuration rather than YAML configuration?"

The answer as @Stephen C suggests is history.  Log4j 2 was released in 2014 and [added YAML and JSON configuration format](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/changelog.html) support.  This means that from 2001 to 2014, your options for log4j configuration files was either XML or properties files (configuration via properties files was removed in log4j 2).